# How can I prevent Docker from launching at login?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I've seen this question asked and answered many times, but nothing has worked for me so far.

I'm using a Macbook Pro running Monterey 12.6, and installed Docker Desktop 4.12.0.
The application opens systematically at login, which I would like to avoid.

I have already switched off the automatic launching from the preferences menu.
[This is my current configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Hx7.png)

I have also tried deleting the scripts from the LaunchAgents list with `launchctl remove`, but that hasn't helped either.

Has anything else worked for someone?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

Docker >> Preferences >> **Unselect** Start Docker when you log in >> Apply & Restart

[image]